# Create std::shared_ptr using factory function

Tags: c++, factory, smart-pointers

I have a class `Foo` which is not instantiated directly but through a static factory method `Foo Foo::create_foo()`.

Now I want to create a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.  Normally I would use

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

How can I achieve the same while using the factory?

I know that I could rewrite `create_foo()` to directly return a pointer but I'm wondering if there is a solution without changing the method.

Comment: What is the full signature of `create_foo`? Does Foo have a copy and/or move constructor?

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Comment: One idea might be to return a `std::unique_ptr` from your factory. This does not enforce additional ownership rules over returning the object directly. Also a `std::unique_ptr` is directly consumable by a `std::shared_ptr`. (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1M4b9v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Foo` class have copy- or rvalue-constructor overloads (implicit or explicit) then you could use it as:

```
auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo::create_foo());
```

Comment: This compiles without error, so I consider it a correct answer. I cannot fully verify as I get some issues at runtime but I think they are related to internals of `Foo` not being moved properly which is beyond the scope of this question.